# PHP installation appears to be missing the "MySQL" extension

Tags: php, mysql

So I was trying to install a PHP script called Sngine, but when I try to install it it shows me this error: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the "MySQL" extension which is required by Sngine. I already have tried editing the php.ini file but it doesn't help. Here's the URL: [zenosyne.ml/social](http://zenosyne.ml/social)

```
PHP Version: 7.0

Apache Version: 2.4.18

Ubuntu Version: 16.04
```

Note: I directly installed LAMP from digital ocean one-click apps

Also, in the documentation it says `mod_rewrite`, `cURL` and `mail()` functions are necessary to be installed", how do I check if they're already installed and if not how do I install them? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `mysql_` was removed in PHP 7 as the docs state. Use PDO or mysqli.... `This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.` I'd question the security of your new library that is using it..

Comment: The mysql_* extensions have been removed as of PHP7, and deprecated after PHP 5.3. It's really recommended to use mysqli or PDO instead. Contact Sngine's support to find out how to get around this. You may need to upgrade your license, find another program, or downgrade your version of PHP.

Comment: @chris85 How do I use mysqli?

Comment: Similarly, all function calls will need to be updated though. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Would it work if I go back to older versions of php and mysql?

Comment: Yes, but it's a bad idea. According to comments on their site, you should open a support ticket at http://support.zamblek.com